# Integrate images to slideshow from database in specific sequence

Tags: php, html

Basically short information about this situation :

I have a slideshow like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWtk8.jpg)

And front-end developer didn't find the easiest solution so here is the front-end code for background images :

```
<div class="item">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 less_spacing"> <img src="{{ url('/dd/img/img/ss/4.jpg') }}"> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 less_spacing"> <img src="{{ url('/dd/img/img/ss/2.jpg') }}"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here for the centre image :

```
 <div class="item" style="background: url(/dd/img/dd/what/1.jpg) center; background-size:cover;">
            <img src="{{ url('/dd/img/dd/what/1.jpg') }}" class="img-responsive hidden-lg hidden-sm hidden-md">
            <span class="sml-logo"><img src="{{ url('/dd/img/sml-logo.png') }}" alt=""></span>
              <div class="caption left_panel">
                <div class="inner">
                  <p>... The key of the door that will open you to the world of gastronomy and history of modern Baltic cuisine, blending international tendencies and interesting selections of wine.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

How you can understand here there is 4 images in this example : the last is 4th.

The centre image is with ID : 1;

I can't make this just based on the ID's from the database because if user will delete some results then +1 -1 will not work for previous and the next image.

Summed up : Basically all I want in this situation is when user clicks on next image the background (left) image changes to the previous centre image and the background(right) side image changes to the next image (3rd) and so on...

Comment: It is not wise to name the image with number ids in your case. Consider changing your database table so that there are id and image name column. In that case, even increment is not working, you can still prioritize the images correctly

Comment: Thank you for your response! So basically when user uploads an image there is select option - for pages, there are 3 pages home/contacts/menu and if user choose home then image is saved in database like : img_time(); when uploaded and category - home, for example, there isn't any ids for image except ID (which is auto increment) in the database table (backgrounds). So you recommend me to make 3 tables? That's not how it will work because if user delete one pic then all will break down! :)